# How to get data efficeiently and show it in DevExpress GridView?

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, sql-server-2016

I've got a sql query which returns 20 columns and about 500 000 rows at this moment. The values are running because people are working on the data in database.
 Most columns in the query isn't simple selects but there is a lot of 'case when'. Data is joined from 5 tables. 
Is there a way to show the data in GridView in efficient manner. Now i show all data (500000 rows) and it takes long time. I've tried pagination but when i want to for example take 100 rows with offset 10 rows, the whole query is executed and it takes to long.
How could i cope with this?

Answer (score 1):

I think you have two sepparte issues here:

1. Slow query: be sure to optimize your query. There are litteraly [thousands of articles](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql%20server%20how%20to%20optimize%20query%20performance) on the net. My first option is always to check indexes on the columns I'm joining the tables by. Start with analyzing [execution plan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/display-an-actual-execution-plan?view=sql-server-ver15), you'll quickly discover the main problem(s).
2. The sheer number of records. 500000 is at least 100 times too big for any human, completly unusable. There are two solutions: limit the number (add another criteria) of returned records or use [Server mode](https://documentation.devexpress.com/WindowsForms/8398/Controls-and-Libraries/Data-Grid/Data-Binding/Large-Data-Sources-Server-and-Instant-Feedback-Modes) for grid.